# How do I add a date column before every output of my mpstat command?

Tags: bash, sed, scripting

I am facing a problem with my scripting.Following is my script.

```
#!/bin/sh
today=`date +%d-%m-%Y`

date +%d-%m-%Y > /usr/etc/Output/$today.txt

mpstat -P ALL | sed -e '1,2d' >>/usr/etc/Output/dfh-$today.txt
```

How will I add a date column before every output of my mpstat command, where I can take the date from my script

Comment: Please edit you Q to add small sample of output from mpstat -P ALL and then required output from that sample input. Do you expect the date/time to dynamically change? Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [xargs(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs). It would be something like this:

```
mpstat -P ALL | sed -e '1,2d' | xargs -I {} date +"%d-%m-%Y {}" >> /usr/etc/Output/dfh-$today.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use double quotes:

```
#!/bin/sh
today=`date +%d-%m-%Y`

date +%d-%m-%Y > "/usr/etc/Output/$today.txt"

mpstat -P ALL | sed -e '1,2d' >> "/usr/etc/Output/dfh-$today.txt"
```

Regards.

Comment: Using double quotes is not solving my problem......... However from my machine double quotes is not needed to indicate output files.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh
today=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y");
mkdir -p /usr/etc/Output/$today &&
date>> /usr/etc/Output/$today/$today.txt
mpstat -P ALL | sed -e '1,2d'>> /usr/etc/Output/$today/$today.txt
```

it may help... let me know..